# MySQL Function return result anomaly

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql 8. Using SQLYog, I tried to create these two similar function, one to pass parameter and one without parameter

```
    CREATE FUNCTION `test_function_with_param`(ucode CHAR(1),uid VARCHAR(10)) RETURNS VARCHAR(50) CHARSET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    READS  SQL DATA 
BEGIN
    RETURN CONCAT(ucode,HEX(SUBSTR(uid,1,2)),HEX(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()));
END$$ 


    CREATE FUNCTION `test_function_without_param`() RETURNS VARCHAR(50) CHARSET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    READS  SQL DATA 
BEGIN
    RETURN CONCAT('A',HEX(SUBSTR('testuser',1,2)),HEX(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()));
END$$
```

And lets say I called select to both function using below query :

```
SELECT test_function_with_param('A','testuser'), test_function_without_param();
```

Try to run the query multiple time, why does return value from test_function_with_param stay the same? Shouldn't both of them  show same return value?

1. [1st query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg4O5.png)
2. [2nd query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2NLP.png)
3. [3rd query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP4Hl.png)

I'm literally confused :(

Comment: Cannot reproduce. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e6cf7054579e036691d9d67a07a2e3c5

Comment: testing using mysql binary client, still got same anomaly.. https://ibb.co/m0tpsKS